# KDE interface and apps lag and shimmer on Fedora 24

Tags: fedora, kde, display, lag

I have Fedora 24 Workstation, on which I later installed KDE. 
For nearly three weeks, everything was fine.
But a week ago, I had my KDE occasionally shimmer with half-transparent interface.

The majority of the apps had problems with interface: overlapping menus, wrong colors, etc., had scrolling lags in Firefox.

Sometimes, the problem persists with numerous restarts, but for me, it happens and ends randomly.

Have you got any idea what it might be?

Comment: This is a kind of problem where an image would speak a 1000 words.  Do make a screenshot.

Comment: @grochmal Of course I will, as soon as it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be having a similar issue. Here's a screenshot:
[image: Blurry KDE]

This happens with varying degrees of blurriness and goes in and out somewhat randomly. I'm on an Asus laptop with NVIDIA proprietary drivers installed.